# How do I call an async instance method in the ActorHandler

Tags: rust, rabbitmq, actor, actix-web

I am trying to implement an actor for rabbitmq (lapin crate) and would like to use it in actix-web context. The struct Queue is already implemented, for connecting, sending and consuming messages.

I am not quite clear how to implement the actor handler for the queue (with the async instance method) correctly.

Here is my attempt:

```rust
struct Queue {
    channel: Channel,
    incoming: String,
    outgoing: String,
}

impl Queue {
    ...
    pub async fn send<T: Serialize>(&self, data: T) {
        let data = serde_json::to_vec(&data);
        match data {
            Ok(data) => {
                let correlation_id = ShortString::from(nanoid!());
                let opts = BasicPublishOptions::default();
                let props = BasicProperties::default().with_correlation_id(correlation_id);
                
                debug!("Sending to: {}", self.outgoing);

                let fut = self
                    .channel
                    .basic_publish(
                        "",
                        &self.outgoing,
                        opts,
                        data,
                        props,
                    )
                    .await;
            }
            Err(err) => {
                warn!("Can't encode an outgoing message: {}", err);
            }
        };
    }
    ...
}

impl Actor for Queue {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}

#[derive(Message)]
#[rtype(result = "()")]
struct SendMessage<T: Serialize>(pub T);

impl<T: Serialize> Handler<SendMessage<T>> for Queue {
    type Result = ();

    fn handle(&mut self, data: SendMessage<T>, ctx: &mut Context<Self>) -> Self::Result {
        let future = self.send(data.0).into_actor(self);
        future.wait(ctx);
    }
}
```

With following compiler error:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> services\email\src\main.rs:327:27
    |
326 |     fn handle(&mut self, data: SendMessage<T>, ctx: &mut Context<Self>) -> Self::Result {
    |               --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
327 |         let future = self.send(data.0).into_actor(self);
    |                      ---- ^^^^
    |                      |
    |                      ...is captured here...
328 |         future.wait(ctx);
    |                ---- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

How could this be made to work?
Maybe someone has already implemented lapin as an actor and can show me how they did it?

Comment: Does specifying `T: 'static` in `SendMessage` works? [`wait()`](https://docs.rs/actix/0.12.0/actix/trait.AsyncContext.html#tymethod.wait) requires the future to be `'static`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything. The error still points to self.

Comment: Where is Handler trait coming from? I feel that the problem is in a way to combine your ActorFuture with this Handler. In Actix it is possible to create async handlers than return futures, so that you don't need to explicitly wait. wait() requires the future to be 'static, but you future can't be static, because it captures &self as an actor.

Comment: The handler trait comes directly from actix (actix::Handler). I have not found an async handler in the documentation. Do you mean actix-web? Or the actor framework actix?